# Purchased a macOS app on a since-abandoned iTunes account, but don't know which account

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I purchased Magic Window a few years (5+) ago using an iTunes account I've since abandoned. The app is prompting for an update, but I cannot remember any details about the account. How can I see what account was used to install this app?

If I can see that, maybe I can try a password reset to be able to log into that account, and get the update.

But I need to see the email address.

PS. The windows that pops up at the moment when I try to update asks for password of an email that is my work email (2 years old) - which is NOT the mail I used to purchase this app.

MacOS Sierra MBP 13 2012.

EDIT: I contacted the company, and within a few minutes the issue was solved. WOW!

Comment: Have you tried contacting that company to see if they have a record of it?

Comment: You might consider editing this question to make it more clear that the core problem is *you don't know which iTunes account/email was originally used to purchase the app*. In particular, I would state this in the question title itself. Assuming, of course, that I'm interpreting your situation correctly.

Comment: @fsb I did contact them, and they helped me immediately!

Comment: Glad they were able to fix it for you!  I would recommend you add what they told you as an answer and not an edit to your question.  That way others who might have the same problem will know there's a solution.

Comment: +1 on adding an official answer to show this has a solution.